# How to add menu item in Blackberry application 

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my app I would like to create a popup sub-menu. How do I do this?

Comment: can you brief your requirement ?

Comment: i am getting data from database that data i want to show on popmenu form that we can select option.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Menus: makeMenu Creates the menu and adds the items in Menu
protected void makeMenu( Menu inMenu, int inInstance )
{
    inMenu.add(showIt1); //inMenu adds the menuItems 
    inMenu.add(showIt2);
    inMenu.add(showIt3);
    super.makeMenu( inMenu, inInstance );
```

/*The class extends MainScreen (net.rim.device.api.ui.container.
MainScreen). As you can probably guess, this is a display class. For
BlackBerry applications, this class provides basic display features, including
supplying a Close menu item. This is achieved by the call to super() in
the constructor.*/

```
}

//Creates menuItems
```

✓"Show It 1": This is the text that the menu item will display.

✓ 50: This ordering parameter determines where in the menu the
item will appear. Lower numbers appear closer to the top of the
menu. In addition, a separator bar is added automatically between two
MenuItems whose ordering values differ by 65536 or more.

✓ 50: This value represents priority, which determines which menu item
is likely to receive the focus. Lower number gets the focus.

```
MenuItem showIt1 = new MenuItem("Show It 1", 50, 50) 
{
        public void run()
        {
            //Do whatever you want
        }
};

MenuItem showIt2 = new MenuItem("Show It 2", 100, 100)
{
        public void run()
        {
            //Do whatever you want
        }
};

MenuItem showIt3 = new MenuItem("Show It 3", 150, 150)
{
        public void run()
        {
            //Do whatever you want
        }
};

//End of Menu Creation
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MenuItem mymenu = new MenuItem("Categories" , 100, 10)
{
    public void run()
    {
       //navigation purposes
    }
}
```

Call this in constructor

```
screen.addMenuItem(mymenu);
```